# Powering 12 V LED strip from a 3.3 V esp32 including PWM

Tags: microcontroller, mosfet, led, led-strip

I'm developing an automation board and want the facility to PWM dim a strip of LEDs  up to 5-10 amps @12 V.

These are plain 2 wire LED strips, positive and negative, nothing special.

My esp32 will be powered via a buck converter from a variable input and I will also have a regulator to level out the 12 V supply.

I have seen projects using the TIP120 for this but I'm not too comfortable with it being at max capacity  so I'm leaning toward a MOSFET. Any suggestions on the best way to power the MOSFET through PWM with 3.3 V logic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest using a N-channel MOSFET, connected between GND and the "-" of the LED.

There are 3 things to check when choosing the N-channel MOSFET :

- that it is fully turned on with only 3.3V (this will eliminate many mosfets) : look for those with a low threshold voltage (well under 3.3V), and then check on the curves if it is really turned completly on at 3.3V
- check that with 3.3V on the gate, the mosfet can carry enough current for your application
- check that the mosfet can handle the heat without extra heatsink (or plan to add the heatsink, but be carefull that even that might not be enough). As a rule of the thumb, the bigger the current rating, the less risk of overheating

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fp1Isn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that you will need the R1 resistor to limit current in your LEDs (excepted if they are already "12V LEDs", in which case they have it probably already included).

Optionnaly, you might want to add a resistor (something like 10k) between gate (ie the pin of the mosfet connected to PWM) and ground to make sure the mosfet is turned off when the esp32 is off (or resseting).

If you choose a really huge N-channel MOSFET, you might need to add a resistor in series between PWM and the gate to limit the current when switching the mosfet (huge N-mos have non negligible capacitance between gate and ground), but it you can avoid it, it's best (adding it makes the mosfet switching slower, therefore increasing the heat produced in it)

Comment: Please can you fix your answer: N-MOS is a technology, not a component type. These are N-channel MOSFETs, so MOSFET instead of N-MOS.

Comment: @TonyM : done. I was always thinking N-MOS was justthe short for N channel mosfet

Comment: I have seen suggestions about using a transistor connected to the 3.3v and 12v then from this into the mosfet, 1 extra component isn't too much hassle.

Regarding the LED strips they have internal resistors and are suitable to be connected directly to 12v source. 

I had also read that i would need a resistor between 3.3 and ground to prevent it being pulled low?

Comment: 1) You could use a transistor to get higher voltage on the gate of the mosfet : but why do it if you can simply choose a mosfet working with 3.3V? (if you where looking for 100A, then it would be difficult to find a MOSFET working with 3.3V, but for 10A you should be fine).

2) if your strip is made to be directly connected on 12V, then you can remove R1

Comment: 3) Where do you get that information that you need a resistor between 3.3V and ground? It would be completly useless (excepted for waist some energy). What might be usefull, is a resistor between gate and GND or 3.3V, depending if you want the LEDs to be on or off by default (ie if the esp32 is not powered, during reset, ...). If you don't care, then no need for this resistor (nb : do not use 2 resistors : either you use one, or none)

Comment: @Sandro in series & pull-down resistors at the gate are possible if in-series are connected first from the MCU output, eliminating the voltage divider at the gate if you meant that.

Comment: Thank you for your help, ill have a look on CPC to find a suitable MOSFET

Comment: @robbrown92 and a one more thing to add - you don't need a high frequency PWM for LED as the eye won't notice anything starting from around 100-200 Hz. So if you get a MOSFET with logic level gate and low gate charge (gate capacitance) when you don't need a series resistor and you can drive it directly from MCU pin. There are some models which fits your needs driving up to 10A @ 3.3Vgs

Comment: Thanks @NStorm If i wanted to use a mosfet as a binary control for a 12v item eg a pump would i then just use a transistor to switch  the high power MOSFET?

Comment: @robbrown92 that depends on MOSFET characteristics, mostly on gate voltage in that case.